# Apache HttpClient Official Example - Releasing Resources method

Tags: apache, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-get

In this official example for Apache HttpClient, there's no mention of releasing  request or response objects. Are they released as part of httpclient.close() or releaseResources method needs to be overridden with something?

```
final CountDownLatch latch2 = new CountDownLatch(1);
final HttpGet request3 = new HttpGet("http://www.apache.org/");
HttpAsyncRequestProducer producer3 = HttpAsyncMethods.create(request3);
AsyncCharConsumer<HttpResponse> consumer3 = new AsyncCharConsumer<HttpResponse>() {

    HttpResponse response;

    @Override
    protected void onResponseReceived(final HttpResponse response) {
        this.response = response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCharReceived(final CharBuffer buf, final IOControl ioctrl) throws IOException {
        // Do something useful
    }

    @Override
    protected void releaseResources() {
    }

    @Override
    protected HttpResponse buildResult(final HttpContext context) {
        return this.response;
    }

};
httpclient.execute(producer3, consumer3, new FutureCallback<HttpResponse>() {

    public void completed(final HttpResponse response3) {
        latch2.countDown();
        System.out.println(request2.getRequestLine() + "->" + response3.getStatusLine());
    }

    public void failed(final Exception ex) {
        latch2.countDown();
        System.out.println(request2.getRequestLine() + "->" + ex);
    }

    public void cancelled() {
        latch2.countDown();
        System.out.println(request2.getRequestLine() + " cancelled");
    }

});
latch2.await();

} finally {
    httpclient.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One needs to override #releaseResources() only if the consumer makes use of system resources such as files, pipes, etc. If response content is always held in memory it gets GCed the normal way.